# Trying to get a specific value from XML attribute

Tags: php, simplexml

Trying to scrape an IKEA page at the following link:

```
http://www.ikea.com/it/it/catalog/products/60255550/?type=xml&dataset=prices
```

I want to scrape the price of the item, but in the xml file the price appears once unformatted and once with the Euro sign next to it. I wish to scrape the priceNormal unformatted value specifically.

```
<prices>
<normal>
<priceNormal unformatted="44.99">€ 44,99</priceNormal>
<pricePrevious/>
<priceNormalPerUnit/>
<pricePreviousPerUnit/>
</normal>
```

My code below doesn't echo the price at all, not sure where I'm going wrong :(

```
$string = 'http://www.ikea.com/it/it/catalog/products/60255550/?type=xml&dataset=prices';

$xml=simplexml_load_file($string) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
//print_r($xml);

echo $xml->product->prices;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the price with

```
$xml->products->product->items->item->prices->normal->priceNormal
$xml->products->product->items->item->prices->normal->priceNormal->attributes()->unformatted
```

If you however need to iterate of a result set, you can break up the places where you are expecting multiples with iteration...

```
foreach( $xml->products->product as $product )
{
  echo $product->name;
  foreach( $product->items->item as $item )
  {
    echo $item->name;
    echo $item->prices->normal->priceNormal;
    echo $item->prices->normal->priceNormal->attributes()->unformatted;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()` to look at the value of `$xml`. It's a bit convoluted, but you'll find the data you're looking for at this location:

```
$xml->products[0]->product->items[0]->item->prices->normal->priceNormal[0];
```

Comment: The value returned still has the Euro symbol attached to it, I was trying to avoid that, any suggestions?

Comment: use `priceNormal[0]->attributes()->unformatted` on the end of @miken32's answer.